# fragment Repeat in tabhost when changing the tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I am working on `FragmentTabHost` with `Fragment`. My `FragmentTabHost` has 4 different `fragments` but when i changing tabs then after some changes 2 or 3 tabs has same fragment. Like index0 index1 index3 has SettingFragment. But they have different `fragment`. This is my code for setup tabs in **MainActivityFragment** which extends `FragmentActivity`

```
private void setTabs() {
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);



//  TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    //Intent intent;

     mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_alert_tab)),
                AlertFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_wlmuser_tab)),
                UserFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_chat_tab)),
                ChatFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_setting_tab)),
                SettingFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    }
```

my 4 fragments are AlertFragment, UserFragment, ChatFragment, SettingFragment and they has buttons. On the click on buttons another fragments open by `FragmentTransaction`

**LIKE** in UserFragment i call ContectFragment in FrameLayout by `inviteBtn` button

```
inviteBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // replace with contact fragment
            fragment = new ContactFragment();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            ft.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            // Start the animated transition.
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

. The problem occur when i open inside `fragments`.

Comment: Please edit your question correct way, let me know in UserFragment inside the tab host you want to replace the fragment in the same activity. what you really want to do can you explain properly.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar my `FragmentTabHost` has 4 different fragments .. but after changing tabs .. 3 tabs has same fragment

Comment: Then what it means  when each fragment has button & click on it button  you want to load another fragment, are you faced the problem when you tried to replace the fragment inside the fragment.

Comment: FragmentTabHost  is decalre inside the activity or fragment

Comment: @BhavdipPathar ... `FragmentTransaction` working fine ,, but when i changing tabs like on index0 tab i click button and then change tab click button of index1 tab .. after doing this index0 and index1 tab has same fragment

Comment: `FragmentTabhost` is Declare in `FragmentActivity`

Comment: Cool  just let me know 4 fragments has button, when we click on appropriate button of selected tab fragment you want to load the another different fragment correct  what i did understood !

Comment: another fragments are loaded successfully. but after loading  fragments with button click my FragmentTabHost has same fragments on all tabs

Comment: The same fragments is what you load on click of button ? or one of the 4 fragments. I mean the fragments you see in each tab click is the same as first time when you load on button click or the fragment out of 4 static fragment

Comment: some time on click of button some time one of 4 fragments

Comment: Can you do one thing do not click on fragment's button just click the different 4 tab let me know do you face the issue.  If you can click on each tab and succesfully visible the appropriate fragment then it might be issue of nested fragment.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar .. You are right .. it is nested fragment issue .. i have already mentioned .. issue come when i click on buttons in fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have fixed you point see below solution. Ideally your have to create one extra BaseContainerFragment. It has the framelayout. In next create the container fragment for each of your four static fragment. let's say I have two fragment with it related container fragment. see below code.

**Original Fragment :**

1. AlertFragment.java
2. ChatFragment.java

**BaseContainerFragment.java**

public class BaseContainerFragment extends Fragment {

```
    public BaseContainerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

    public boolean popFragment() {
        boolean isPop = false;
        if (getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            isPop = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        return isPop;
    }

}
```

**Container Fragment which extends the above BaseContainerFragment:**

1. AlertContainerFragment.java extends BaseContainerFragment.java
2. ChatContainerFragment.java extends BaseContainerFragment.java

Now In your FragmentActivity you have to add ContainerFragment of each fragment inside FragmentTabHost.see the below code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class TestSukhwantTabHost extends FragmentActivity  {

    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_sukhwant_tab_host);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),AlertContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator(null, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),ChatContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Now I post the Container Fragment code, this container fragment actually load our original Fragment. To load the fragment inside the fragment we used the container fragment method to replace the new fragment.

**fragment_base_container.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 </FrameLayout>
```

**AlertContainerFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class AlertContainerFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_container, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        replaceFragment(new AlertFragment(), false);
    }
}
```

**ChatContainerFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class ChatContainerFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {


    public ChatContainerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_container, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        replaceFragment(new ChatFragment(), false);
    }
}
```

**Original Fragment :**

Below is **AlertFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class AlertFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button framgnet1_button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alert, container, false);
        framgnet1_button = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.framgnet1_button);
        framgnet1_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(new DynamicAlertFramgnet(), false);
            }
        });
        return mView;
    }
}
```

**ChatFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    private Button button_chart_fragment;

    public ChatFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
        button_chart_fragment = (Button)mView.findViewById(R.id.button_chart_fragment);
        button_chart_fragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(new DynamicChartFramgnet(), false);
            }
        });
        return mView;
    }
}
```

In above code what i had implemented, each original fragment has button when you click on it, it will load the new fragment.

Let me know if you have any question & pleas give your suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() giving compiler error of undefined method for onClick so i change it ot getFragmentManager bt then same problem

Comment: In your posted code I see mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

Comment: it is in FragmentActivity but buttons are in fragments

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Hi I have edit the answer please review it let me give your suggestion  hope sure help you :)